# IE Conditional CSS

Tags: css, internet-explorer, browser

I have a few stylesheets i want to load up depending on the IE version. Pretty straight forward stuff except any time i view the website in IE, none of the style sheets seemed to be being loaded.

```
<!--[if IE 7]>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ie7.css">
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ie8.css">
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9]>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ie9.css">
<![endif]-->
```

It looks fine to me, can't seem to figure out why the version specific style sheets aren't loading.

I have done multiple refreshes incase it was just a cache issue but nothing seems to be making any difference.

Any ideas.

Comment: If you remove the comments, do all of your stylesheets load correctly?

Comment: Yes, no issues loading them without the conditional statements. Except they still do not appear in IE browsers for some weird reason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your conditional statements are correct.

Make sure they are linked properly by loading them without the statements.

Edit: Make sure to close the link tags.

Comment: Without the conditional statements, the css loads in every browser (as expected) except the IE browsers.

Comment: possibly because you do not close the link tag. need the />

Comment: Seems to be working again now? Think it was some weird cache issue.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [HTML5 Boilerplate](http://www.html5boilerplate.com/) for a potentially better and more maintainable solution, using one style sheet reference shared across all browsers. Root level classes are applied in order to target specific browsers from one style sheet.

```
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html lang="en-us" class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>    <html lang="en-us" class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>    <html lang="en-us" class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html lang="en-us" class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
```

Comment: What does this do to answer the question?

Comment: It gives an alternative solution if a solution cannot be found or the initial problem fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You mention that without the conditions the stylesheets load fine in all browsers except Internet Explorer.

This suggests that there is not an issue with your conditions, but with your links. You are not closing your link tags, and Internet Explorer may be more strict about this than other browsers. Try changing your markup to the following:

```
<!--[if IE 7]>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ie7.css" type="text/css" />
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ie8.css" type="text/css" />
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9]>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ie9.css" type="text/css" />
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: I closed the link tags and its still acting weird. I think its some sort of cache issue, its now picking and choosing when to load new stylesheets rather than on every refresh.

Comment: @JMcNelis - I've edited my answer slightly to include a `type`. This will give the browser more information on what this link is, and may help with your cache issue. Ensure you are forcing a full browser refresh each time you reload.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you try with any one conditional CSS statement either 7,8 or 9 and then add the remaining two. Also, depends on the unique CSS applicable to IE only. Try changing some basic properties of a div.

For example, your general CSS for a div may look like this

```
#sample {border:solid 5px red;}
```

For IE - Put this css in any one of the css ie. ie7.css / ie8.css / ie9.css

```
#sample {border:solid 5px green;}
```

Think this should work.